# iPhone lose array info on swipe, can't display anything

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gestures

I have an array of HTML strings, and I'm trying to have the next string appear in a UIWebView every time the user swipes. Based on my output, the problem seems to be that when I load the first HTML string in viewWillAppear, the array is all there and the first HTML string appears in the webview, but once I register the swipe in swipedRight or swipedLeft, when I check the array it is empty all of sudden. I have the array as a property in the class so I can't figure out why this is happening. Feel like its something stupid..

I'm new at asking questions (and Objective-C) so let me know if there's anything else you need..

In the header...

```
@property (nonatomic, weak)NSArray * slideDesctiptions;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
```

And here is the code for my implementation..

```
@interface TestViewController () <ArticleTableViewControllerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet TestView* testView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* description;
@property int marker;
@end

@implementation TestViewController
@synthesize slideDescriptions = _slideDescriptions;
@synthesize description = _description;
@synthesize marker = _marker;

@synthesize testView = _testView;
@synthesize webView = _webView;

-(void)setTestView:(TestView *)testView {
    _testView = testView;
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipedRight:)];
    [swipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
    [self.testView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipedLeft:)];
    [swipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    [self.testView addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
   // [self.testView addSubview:self.webView];

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{       
        self.marker =0;
    self.description = [self.slideDescriptions objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"description %@",[self.description description]);
            NSLog([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"count %d", [self.slideDescriptions count]]description]);


    self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    [self.testView addSubview:self.webView];
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:self.description baseURL:nil];
}


    -(void)swipedRight :(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) gesture{
 NSLog([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"count %d", [self.slideDesctiptions count]]description]);
        if ((gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
            || (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)){
            NSLog(@"swiped right");
            self.marker ++;
            NSLog([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"count %d", [self.slideDescriptions count]]description]);
    NSLog(@"description to be shown %@",[self.description description]);
            self.description = [self.slideDesctiptions objectAtIndex:self.marker];
            [self.webView loadHTMLString:self.description baseURL:nil];
        }
    }
    -(void)swipedLeft :(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) gesture{
        if ((gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
            || (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)){
            NSLog(@"swipted left");
            self.marker --;
            self.description = [self.slideDesctiptions objectAtIndex:self.marker];
            [self.webView loadHTMLString:self.description baseURL:nil];
        }
    }

@end
```

Output:

```
2013-06-24 10:59:44.300 PlairTest[1667:c07] description <p>We are now roughly one month from the 2013 MLB All-Star Game, with two-and-a-half months of the 2013 season now in the books.</p><p>As the weeks pass, there is more and more separation between the contenders and the non-contenders, but this past week showed that things are still far from decided.&nbsp;</p><p>The San Diego Padres, Kansas City Royals and Toronto Blue Jays checked in at 18-20 in last week's power rankings and went a combined 16-3 last week. Meanwhile, the Rangers and Yankees stood at No. 5 and No. 6, and they went a combined 2-11.&nbsp;</p><p>Those were not the only surprises this past week, and needless to say, there was plenty of shakeup in the rankings as a result.</p><p>So here is a look at this week's updated <a href="http://bleacherreport.com/articles/1630131-updated-mlb-power-rankings">MLB power rankings</a>, with the focus this week being on who each team's five most valuable players are right now, according to WAR. Be sure to check back here each Monday morning for an updated look at where your favorite team stands.</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p><em>*Note: All WAR statistics courtesy of <a href="http://www.fangraphs.com/">FanGraphs.com</a> and current through June 15. All other statistics current through June 16.</em></p>
2013-06-24 10:59:44.301 PlairTest[1667:c07] count 31
2013-06-24 10:52:38.563 PlairTest[1646:c07] count 0
2013-06-24 10:52:38.564 PlairTest[1646:c07] swiped right
2013-06-24 10:52:38.564 PlairTest[1646:c07] count 0
2013-06-24 10:52:38.564 PlairTest[1646:c07] slide to be shown (null)
2013-06-24 10:52:38.564 PlairTest[1646:c07] description <p>We are now roughly one month from the 2013 MLB All-Star Game, with two-and-a-half months of the 2013 season now in the books.</p><p>As the weeks pass, there is more and more separation between the contenders and the non-contenders, but this past week showed that things are still far from decided.&nbsp;</p><p>The San Diego Padres, Kansas City Royals and Toronto Blue Jays checked in at 18-20 in last week's power rankings and went a combined 16-3 last week. Meanwhile, the Rangers and Yankees stood at No. 5 and No. 6, and they went a combined 2-11.&nbsp;</p><p>Those were not the only surprises this past week, and needless to say, there was plenty of shakeup in the rankings as a result.</p><p>So here is a look at this week's updated <a href="http://bleacherreport.com/articles/1630131-updated-mlb-power-rankings">MLB power rankings</a>, with the focus this week being on who each team's five most valuable players are right now, according to WAR. Be sure to check back here each Monday morning for an updated look at where your favorite team stands.</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p><em>*Note: All WAR statistics courtesy of <a href="http://www.fangraphs.com/">FanGraphs.com</a> and current through June 15. All other statistics current through June 16.</em></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array property is weak:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak)NSArray * slideDesctiptions;
```

Basically, that means that ARC will deallocate (destroy) your array straight after you store it. You should change that to `strong` instead:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *slideDesctiptions;
```

Quick note, your web view property is correct to be weak:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
```

That's because it's an `IBOutlet` and it's being retained by its superview. You don't want to make it strong.

(so there's a good chance that `testView` should be changed to `weak` as you currently have it as `strong`)